# Из C++ consol application в Qt GUI

Tags: qt, c++

Допустим, у меня есть класс, одним из методов которого является вывод в консоль содержимого некоторого массива.

К примеру:

```
void Class::Out()
{
    int i = 0;  
    while(i < max_size)  
    {  
        cout << arr[i];  
        i++;
    }
}
```

Мне нужно, что бы этот метод выполнился в Qt по нажатию кнопки и вывел содержимое массива в `TextEdit`.

Как я понимаю, необходимо заменить `cout` на

```
ui->TextEdit->SetText(arr[i]);
```

Экземпляр класса Class создать в main файле, после чего сделать вызов метода object.Out() в функции нажатия кнопки. Но я не понимаю, что куда подключить, чтобы они друг друга видели и понимали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш класс Class понятия не имеет, что такое ui, и о каком TextEdit идет речь. Поэтому я бы сделал arr[] доступным для "внешних кодов" и ui->TextEdit->SetText(arr[i]) поместил в обработчик кнопки.